# Erro ao executar programa em C "No such file or directory"

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Estou tentando executar um programa em C, porém um erro ocorre

Faço os seguintes passos:

```
gcc -c prog.c -o prog
/.prog
```

E aparece isso:

```
bash: /.prog: No such file or directory
```

Comment: É ./prog , não /.prog

Comment: Também precisas *linkar* com a biblioteca padrão. O parametro `-c` pára o processo de criação dum executável antes da *linkagem*. O resultado **não é** executável. Chama o compilador sem o `-c`: `gcc -Wall prog.c -o prog`.